# Cannot access virtual directories on Drupal 7

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualhost, php5, httpd.conf

I have installed Drupal 7.37 on AWS EC2 Linux instance. It was working perfectly until I reinstalled httpd24 and PHP 5.5. Since then, the main page loads perfectly but I cannot access my virtual directories. For instance, when I click on Drupal's button "Login" it tries to load `mypage.com/user/logout` (I have clean URLs activated), but I get error 404.

This is my VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mypage.com
    ServerAlias mypage.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/drupal7
</VirtualHost>
```

And Directory:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/drupal7">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Where should I search for the problem? httpd.conf or php.ini?

**EDIT1:** Access logs output when I try to access one of these pages. No error log outputs:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [14/May/2015:16:35:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18900 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [14/May/2015:16:35:55 +0000] "GET /admin/structure/block?render=overlay HTTP/1.1" 404 219 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36"
```

**EDIT2:** I have another website with virtual directories running on /var/www/html and it works perfectly. But this one (/usr/share/drupal7) doesn't.

**EDIT3:** I just tried moving my page to /var/www/html and I get the same problem. Could it be a drupal issue while creating these virtual directories (e.g., /admin /artefacts /user)? .htaccess?

Comment: Did you check the httpd logs?

Comment: It looks like that this snippet has been retrieved from the access log. Did you check the error log as well?

Comment: There are no errors at all. It looks to me that I do have permissions to visit mypage.com but not mypage.com/whatever. Could it be the case?

Comment: Could you check whether `/usr/share/drupal7` is not empty and check the owner and group of this folder? The httpd has been restarted once the httpd.conf was changed?

Comment: The directory has content (and it actually shows the index properly), the owner and group are "root" as expected. httpd restarted without consecuences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! I just needed to edit the directory with AllowOverride All, as per below:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/drupal7">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```